# AEM6.5 scheduled activation status icon is not shown

Tags: icons, aem, status, activation

I've seen that in earlier versions of AEM, when we schedule a page to get activated at a later time, a small calendar icon is showing up under the status column. When we hover over this icon, it displays the scheduled date and time.

But, I can't see that scheduled activation calendar icon anymore. I can only see the workflow icon under the status column.

Is there a way how I can display the scheduled activation status icon in AEM 6.5?

Many thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should still be visible by default in AEM 6.5 so you may not need any custom implementation. If it isn't working, maybe there's a bug or there's an existing customization that's preventing those icons from working.

## In the list view

In the column that displays the publication status, there's a faint calendar icon. It's quite low-contrast though. Hovering over it will reveal the scheduled publication date.

[image: The AEM Sites console in list view, showing a list of we-retail demo pages. One page is pending activation. The 'Published' column shows the replication status of the page. Next to the page scheduled for activation, there's a calendar icon. The cursor is hovering over the icon and a pop up reveals there's a publication scheduled for the next day and that it was scheduled by the Administrator. On the left hand side, the 'Timeline' rail is open and it shows that a workflow has been started.]

## In the card view

You should be able to see the time of scheduled activation in the page preview on the right hand side.

[image: AEM Sites console, open in the Card view, showing an example we-retail page. The page is selected. There's a preview on the right hand side that lists the page metadata, including the replication status and the replication schedule. On the left hand side, the 'Timeline' rail is open and it shows that a workflow has been started.]

## How you could change or add icons

If you still want to add an icon, you should be able to achieve this via overlaying parts of the sites console. You'd have to find the right scripts under `/libs` and create an overlay under `/apps`

This is also where you'd look if any icons available OOTB are missing.

More on the subject:

- [Using the Sling Resource Merger](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/platform/sling-resource-merger.html?lang=en#:%7E:text=The%20Sling%20Resource%20Merger%20provides,using%20the%20configured%20search%20paths)
- [Customizing the consoles](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/extending-aem/customizing-consoles-touch.html?lang=en)